# Accessing occurrence groups for high frequency elements in list

Tags: python, list

I have several lists where some of the elements occur in more than one. An example would be

```
lst[0]
Output: [1,2,3]

lst[1]
Output: [1,2]

lst[2]
Output: [3]
```

So far, I have calculated the occurrence of each element below

```
flat = [i for sub in lst for i in sub] #Group A will be lst[0] and so on
tmp = Counter(flat)
counts = Counter(tmp.values())
counts
Output: Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})
```

Now, I want to pull out the groups for elements that occur more than once, i.e. `2` will correspond to `Group A` and `Group B`. I am thinking of writing a for loop to check occurrence of each qualified element for all the groups, but this seems inefficient.

Comment: This isn't clear enough.  First, your posted code fails to define `lst`; the table you posted does not imply a particular data structure.  Also, your given counts do not match the data in the table.

Comment: I have updated the question. It should be clear now.

Comment: Your update is confusing. Your example has the values in `c`, but then your code works on `lst`. Also, the fact that you have to type `list(c[0])` instead of just `c[0]` implies that `c` may be a list of iterators or something?

Comment: Also, what is the second `Counter` for? `tmp` gives you the output you say you have (if you run it on `c` instead of `lst`); `counts` gives you `Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}`, the number of times each _count_ appears, which seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a list of groups for each element, instead of just a count of appearances.

So, you obviously can't just use a `Counter`, because that explicitly maps values to counts, not lists. But you can just use a `dict`.

And you also obviously can't flatten the list before building the dict, because that throws away the group information that you wanted to store.

And meanwhile, don't worry about trying to write the whole thing as a one-liner. Write something that you can understand first, and then you can see if you can condense it once it's working.

---

So:

```
groupmapping = {}
for i, group in enumerate(lst):
    for elem in group:
        groupmapping.setdefault(element, list()).append(i)
```

… or:

```
groupmapping = defaultdict(list)
for i, group in enumerate(lst):
    for elem in group:
        groupmapping[element].append(i)
```

If you plan to use `groupmapping` as a normal `dict` that should raise `KeyError` instead of returning `[]` on a failed lookup, then do the first one, but here, it looks like you're just using it for this purpose, so a `defaultdict` makes more sense. (It'll also be a bit faster, if that matters.)

If your values can't be repeated within a group—or if they can, but you want to ignore that and collapse all appearances within a group—just replace the `list` with `set` and the `append` with `add`.

If you wanted names for the groups instead of indices, you must have those names somewhere, e.g., `names = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C']`. If so, just replace `enumerate(list)` with `zip(names, list)`.

---

Now, to get the groups of every repeated element:

```
for value, groups in groupmapping.items():
    if len(groups) > 1:
        print(f'{value} appears multiple times, in groups {groups}')
```

---

This is fine for efficiency. Sure, that second loop takes linear time `O(M)` in the number of distinct elements, but your original loop (whether hidden inside a `Counter` call or written out explicitly) already takes linear time `O(N)` in the number of total elements, and `O(N+M)` where `M < N` is just `O(N)`.

And, more to the point, you obviously can't beat `O(M)` for any process that generates a sequence of `M` values.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to iterate over your groups at least once to figure out if there is an element in them. For exceptionally large groups and multiple lookups it might be beneficial to turn them into sets and then check for an element instead of iterating through them (as iteration is much slower once on the Python side of things), but that's as far as you can take it. There is no need to count the rest of the elements, either, if you're only interested in the presence of one.

So, a simple function:

```
def get_groups(src, contains, minimum=2):
    res = [x for x in src if contains in x]
    if len(res) >= minimum:
        return res
```

Should be more than you need. You can then use it as:

```
c = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]  # etc.

print(get_groups(c, 2))     # [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
print(get_groups(c, 3))     # None
print(get_groups(c, 2, 3))  # None
print(get_groups(c, 1, 3))  # [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]
```